# Prevent PHP scripts from running concurrently

Tags: php, session-variables, cron, web-crawler

I have a cron script that would spider a website for new content and save the entries I need into the database. Entries are md5 hashed and validated, to prevent dupes. However I have noticed that there are sometimes two occurrences running at the same time, and the hashing method is failing at this point as I get two of each pregmatches inserted into DB.

Can someone recommend the best way to prevent this from happening in the future.

I have considered locking execution by checking log files, but in this case the script may get permanently locked if there is an error in the middle.

I'm looking into setting $_SESSION['lock'], so in this case if it locks and breaks, the session is bound to expire at some point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly use the locking idea you've got, but include a LastActive timestamp? Then your script can check the last active timestamp on initiation, and if it's been over 10 minutes or so, unlock and continue.

Comment: a Memcache-based mutex system. Expiration built-in :)

Comment: When your script starts up, you could check to see if a script of the same name is already running, from `ps`. If it is, exit the new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `$_SESSION` should be left when running from a web server, not command line.

I would store last activity time in a file. If cron finishes its work normally, you delete the file.

When cron script runs, check the file. If file doesn't exist, or, last activity is older than a certain time span, you continue to execute, otherwise - stop.

This would be pretty easy to implement too.

Check, if script should run:

```
if(file_exists('lock.txt') && file_get_contents('lock.txt') > (time() - 60)){
   die('Should not run!');
}
```

Log activity on certain script's life-cycle points:

```
file_put_contents('lock.txt', time());
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, but with extra DB entry, rather than actual log file. Still not sure which of those two is better, though. It's down to extra DB conn against extra READ/WRITE.

Comment: Also, yes, it didn't occur to me before, but sessions aren't working from terminal. WHich makes perfect sense, actually.

Comment: Database anyway ends up with a physical read/write :) I just think that file_put/get_contents is super handy function, easy to use too, so the code is shorter than a select/insert in a database. Anyway, the main thing is the idea.